# How to pass template variable to component without ViewChild

Tags: javascript, angular, viewchild

I need to pass a component A to another component B.
Component B needs access to the nativeElement of A.
I managed to get it to work like this:

### Container

#### Template

```
<component-a #componentA></component-a>

<component-b [origin]="reference"></component-b>
```

#### Controller

```
@ViewChild('componentA', {read: ElementRef}) reference: ElementRef;
```

### Component B

```
 @Input() origin: ElementRef;
```

---

**Is there a way to get it to work without ViewChild, just with passing the template reference?**

It should look like this:

```
<component-a #componentA></component-a>

<component-b [origin]="componentA"></component-b>
```

Right now if I do it like this I cannot access the nativeElement.

Comment: You can also add `constructor(public elRef: ElementRef)` to `component-a` and pass it like `componentA.elRef`. Within template the template reference variable `#componentA` will always refer to component instance in your case

Comment: The thing is I would like to be able to do this with any component. With your solution I would need to override all components and add ElementRef to the contructor

Comment: Why do you need to pass whole component to another component as a parameter?

Comment: @omeralper I need to clone the native element, do some changes and display it inside the other component

Answer (score 0):

You can write the service class which can refer to the component and inject the service wherever you require to use the referred component.

```
@Component
class Component1 implements OnInit{

   constructor(private ShareService : ShareService, private ref : ElementRef){

   }

   public ngOnInit(){
       this.shareService.sharedComponent = this.ref;
   }
}

ShareService {

   public sharedComponent;

}
```

Better design would be to have `sharedComponent` as Observable.